# Programmatically Encrypting web.config using RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider gives Internal Server Error 105.23

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, web-config, rsa

I am trying to encrypt sections of my `web.config` file through RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider programmatically. But at the time of encryption When it reach to `SAVE();` It throws an exception **System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Object already exists.**

But if I encrypt it using **DataProtectionConfigurationProvider** it encrypts the section but when I run the application It gives 
**HTTP Error 500.23 - Internal Server Error**

What could be the solution of it?

One more question I'm doing it all in `SQLDataSource` to read the connectionstring in the `web.config` file. Is this thing won't work if the `web.config` encrypted?

Here is my code :

```
 private void ProtectSection(string sectionName, string provider)
 {
     CspParameters cspParams;
     const int PROVIDER_RSA_FULL = 1;
     const string CONTAINER_NAME = "NetFrameworkConfigurationKey";
     cspParams = new CspParameters(PROVIDER_RSA_FULL);
     cspParams.KeyContainerName = CONTAINER_NAME;
     cspParams.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
     cspParams.ProviderName = "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider";

     CryptoKeyAccessRule rule = new CryptoKeyAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null), CryptoKeyRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);

     cspParams.CryptoKeySecurity = new CryptoKeySecurity();
     cspParams.CryptoKeySecurity.SetAccessRule(rule);

     Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.openWebConfiguration(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);

     ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection(sectionName);

     if (section != null && !section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
     {
        section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(provider);
        config.Save();
     }
 }

 private void UnProtectSection(string sectionName)
 {
    Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.openWebConfiguration(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath);

    ConfigurationSection section = config.GetSection(sectionName);

    if (section != null && section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
    {
      section.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection();
      config.Save();
    }
 }
```

Help Would Be much appreciated. THanks in Advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to encrypt only by programmatically? There seems many examples using aspnet and also by programmatically. RSA would be better option preventing decryption by black people. For second, as private opinion, I think it will be not affected because encrypted web.config will be automatically decrypted.

Comment: Yes that is correct and I tried that option.
But the problem is i need to append a salt with userID or password. So that is why I am considering this option.

Comment: Oh, I see..Just kindly understand that I'd recommend another way if the encryption will be done only 1 time for web.config..Hope you find good solution..

Answer (score 0):

please find the below link which asks you give rights for the machine keys. Just give access for the iisuser / everyone and try the same. this works fine. The machine keys folder can be found in any one of the following folder

•\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys
•\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys

Thank you

Comment: I don't think giving the "Everyone" group access to these folders is a secure thing to do...